# Reactjs : how to auto select and disable few selectbox options, while others are open for selection maually, from array

Tags: reactjs

REACTJS: Attached JSON shows "Success" and "Failure" data. I am storing these in a single array and then populating into one select box, which is working fine.
Now in the select box, the options that were read from "Success" should be visible as disabled, by default.

I am using material-UI as of now. Any suggestions, please. Sample JSON attached

[image]

Comment: Really stuggling to understand what you're asking / trying to do.  Can you rephrase with more detail?  And some code of what you've tried?

Comment: I have rephrased it. Does this makes sense now

Comment: Definitely more understandable.  Post your code as well, so we can see what you're working with.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to give the solution I followed. Added checked property to the object using forEach loop on the object. Set it as true for the default selection and vicaversa. It worked